Is this class between BPP and PP?
In analogy to BPP, I define a class XYZ (maybe it already has a name) as follows. For every language $L$ in XYZ, there is an algorithm $M$, such that:

$M$ runs in polynomial time on the size of its input;
$M$ returns either 0, 1, or 'I DO NOT KNOW' (at variance with BPP!);
the probability of getting either 0 or 1 does not vanish;
for all $x$ in $L$, the probability of getting 1 from $M$ when it does not return 'I DO NOT KNOW' is greater than or equal to 2/3
for all $x$ not in $L$, the probability of getting 1 from $M$ when it does not return 'I DO NOT KNOW' is less than or equal to 1/3

To better clarify: the probabilities mentioned in points 4 and 5 are calculated on the 0 or 1 outputs, thus neglecting the 'I DO NOT KNOW' values. E.g., for a given algorithm and a given $x$, if the algorithm outputs 0 with overall probability 2%, 1 with overall probability 6%, and 'I DO NOT KNOW' with overall probability 92%, the probability mentioned in points 4 and 5 is 75%, i.e. 6%/(2%+6%).
I think that BPP $\subseteq$ XYZ $\subseteq$PP, i.e. the class I am asking about is between BPP and PP:
BPP$\subseteq$XYZ because the algorithm required in BPP is also a valid algorithm for XYZ, even if it always returns 0 or 1 (and never 'I DO NOT KNOW')
XYZ$\subseteq$PP because we can extend any algorithm of XYZ to a valid algorithm for PP by randomly returning 0 or 1 when 'I DO NOT KNOW' is returned in first place
I also think that NP $\subseteq$ XYZ; the proof follows the proof of NP $\subseteq$ PP. So XYZ is likely larger than BPP. However, I do not understand if XYZ is equal to PP. Informally, I do not see reasons why the algorithm requested by PP can be extended to a lazy algorithm required by XYZ increasing its success rate.
Is this class known in literature? Does it have a name? Is it studied? Is it really different from PP? Any comment is welcome.

This is in the polynomial hierarchy ($\mathrm{BPP^{NP}}$, I guess) by approximate counting: approximate the number of random sequences that make $M$ return $1$, resp. $0$, within a factor of, say, $4/3$, and return whichever is larger. Thus, it is most likely smaller than PP.

It is very interesting, I think that it would be valuable to expand this comment into a full answer. I know that this site is for professionals, but this discussion is not trivial for me and a longer explanation could help other users, in view of multidisciplinarity.

Well, I can't do that now as I'm on vacation.

Isn't it BPP_path or sometimes called PostBPP? Conditioning on not "I don't know" seems like a postselection.

Yes, it is! It matches with the definition of PostBPP in https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0606140v4. The paper also shows that PostBPP is included in BPP^NP and explains the connection with the counting (so, we do not have to disturb the vacations of Emil Jerabek!) Thanks again to both.

Yes, it's good to see the complexity zoo for a quick summary: https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:B#bpppath
Also, note that the quantum analog PostBQP is equal to PP, as shown by Aaronson.

Then PostBQP strictly includes PostBPP, unless PH collapses. Is the relation between PostBPP and BQP known? Based on the conjecture that BQP is not included in PH, we can say that BQP is not included in PostBPP as well. Is there a proof based on more robust conjectures (like PH does not collapse)?
